# CANopen CANmessage blocking

Tags: microcontroller, can, robotics

Is there a trick to block CAN messages from a specific device?
I have to block some of CAN messages of my remote controller so that I can send my CAN messages via my Laptop. Otherwise my messages gets overwritten all the time.

Not all the messages should be blocked since the emergency button on the remote controller should be kept.

Comment: Question is unclear. Specify how you send your CAN messages. CAN is just a protocol.

Comment: I am sending my CAN messages using the software named PCAN-View. The problem is that it gets overwritten from the remote controller so that my message gets overwritten the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a trick to block CAN messages from a specific device?

No. With CAN bus you are unable to determine which node is transmitting. Meaning you cannot block a device.

It is also not possible to block a message, since this will result in the transmitting device going bus-off if the error is not cleared after 255 transmit failures.
Even if you wanted to interfere with one message, you'd need custom hardware to do so.

CAN bus is a broadcast network. If you do not want a device to transmit a certain message, you have to disable the message in the device, or prevent the device from transmitting it on the bus on the first place. With a bridge for example.

Comment: The device is transmitting the CAN messsages automatically, I think it is designed like that. So the only way out is to put a microcontroller so that I can filter the messages.

Comment: Do you have any recommended documentation for this?

Comment: @joe [product1](https://www.helmholz.de/en/products/fieldbus-applications/can-bus/infrastructure/can-bridge/), [product2](https://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/gateways-and-bridges/canbridge) or [diy](https://copperhilltech.com/blog/can-bus-bridge-cantocan-application-with-arduino-due/)

Comment: For my case where the remote controller is physically connected to the CANbus, the bridge does not work... see my electrical circuit ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pGd2Iyol1XLpPlkiYR8m0SDRjt-HUigC ). The best way would be to deactivating the CAN 1 and to connect my Laptop to CAN 2, but if that is also not possible... Will there be another solution?

Comment: @Joe You have physically disconnect the remote from the CAN bus and insert the bridge. There is no other way.

Comment: The CAN HIGH and CAN LOW of radio receiver are physically connected to CAN1. So the information from the radio receiver is ALWAYS going in to CAN bus, as I marked here ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pGd2Iyol1XLpPlkiYR8m0SDRjt-HUigC)  Am I reading this circuit correctly?

Comment: @Joe I can see two terminals, 4 and 5, you can disconnect these. Let's stop using the comments as chat.